Requiring Menu Collapse upon Category Selection
I'm currently facing a challenge in resolving the issue of collapsing the menu again after a category is clicked. I suspect that the problem lies with the "display: none" property persisting even when the "first" class has been assigned the "first-grid" class. This forces me to use the "!important" style declaration to override it. Would you be able to provide assistance in finding a solution to this problem?


$(document).ready(function () {
var header = $(".menu-gift");
var sticky = header.offset().top;

function toggleSecondVisibility() {
  var second = $(".second");
  second.click(function () {
    var first = $(".first");
    if (second.css("display") === "flex") {
      var arrow = $(".drop-arrow");
      first.toggleClass("first-grid");
      arrow.toggleClass("arrow-rotate");
    }
  });
}

function FirstMenuChangeOrder(scrollPos) {
  if (window.innerWidth < 1199) {
    var first = $(".first");
    var second = $(".second");

    if (scrollPos > sticky) {
      header.addClass("sticky");
      first.hide();
      second.show();
    } else {
      header.removeClass("sticky");
      first.show();
      second.hide();
    }
  }
}

function ChangeActiveOnScroll(scrollPos) {
  // Top positions of all sections
  var mostGiftedTop = $("#most-gifted").offset().top;
  var initialJewelryTop = $("#initial-jewerly").offset().top;
  var multiNameTop = $("#multi-name").offset().top; // Assuming you have sections with class 'multi-name'
  var under150Top = $("#under-150").offset().top; // Assuming you have sections with class 'under-150'

  // Remove 'active' class from all navigation links
  $(".menu-gift .first a").removeClass("active");

  // Element to display the name of the active section
  var choosenSection = $(".choosen-section");

  // Check the current scroll position against section top positions and update accordingly
  if (scrollPos >= under150Top) {
    // If scroll position is at or below "Under $150"
    $(".under-150 a").addClass("active");
    choosenSection.text("UNDER $150");
  } else if (scrollPos >= multiNameTop) {
    // If scroll position is at or below "Multi-Name"
    $(".multi-name a").addClass("active");
    choosenSection.text("MULTI-NAME");
  } else if (scrollPos >= initialJewelryTop) {
    // If scroll position is at or below "Initial Jewelry"
    $(".initial-jewerly a").addClass("active");
    choosenSection.text("INITIAL JEWELRY");
  } else if (scrollPos >= mostGiftedTop) {
    // If scroll position is at or below "Most Gifted"
    $(".most-gifted a").addClass("active");
    choosenSection.text("MOST GIFTED");
  }
  // Continue with more sections if needed
}

function setupSmoothScroll() {
  $(".menu-gift .first a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default anchor click behavior
    var targetId = $(this).attr("href");
    var targetPosition = $(targetId).offset().top - header.outerHeight() - 50; // Adjust if you have a sticky header
    $("html, body").animate(
      {
        scrollTop: targetPosition,
      },
      600
    ); // 600ms scroll animation
  });
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop() + 200;
  var scrollPosNoOffset = $(document).scrollTop();
  FirstMenuChangeOrder(scrollPos - 155);
  ChangeActiveOnScroll(scrollPos);
});

// Initial state checks
var initialScrollPos = $(document).scrollTop() + 200;
var initialScrollPosNoOffset = $(document).scrollTop();
FirstMenuChangeOrder(initialScrollPos - 155);
ChangeActiveOnScroll(initialScrollPos);
toggleSecondVisibility();
setupSmoothScroll();
});
.first {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  row-gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 56px;
    padding-top: 28px;
    padding-bottom: 28px;
  }
}
.first-grid {
  order: 2;
  display: grid !important;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-gift">
    <div class="first">
      <span class="most-gifted"
        ><a class="active" href="#most-gifted">MOST GIFTED</a></span
      >
      <span class="initial-jewerly"
        ><a href="#initial-jewerly">INITAL JEWERLY</a></span
      >
      <span class="multi-name"><a href="#multi-name">MULTI NAME</a></span>
      <span class="under-150"><a href="#under-150">UNDER $150</a></span>
      <span><a href="">UNDER $250</a></span>
      <span><a href="">FINE JEWELRY</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <span class="you-choose">Gift guide:</span>
      <span class="choosen-section">MOST GIFTED</span>
      <img
        class="drop-arrow"
        src="https://cdn.myka.com/digital-asset/banners/drop-down-arrow-gift-guide.svg" />
    </div>
</div>



In order to better understand it look like that


Your code in this question is not working. Please turn it into a snippet that we can test.

@LajosArpad How to do this

There is a <> snippet in the question editor when you edit your question. You can click on that, which will add a snippet and you can paste your HTML, Javascript and CSS alike and test the code. I have started writing an answer for you and was about to create a snippet, but the code was not operational as it is, not even if I have chosen to add jQuery. You will need to add a snippet to your question and make it a workable snippet, so we can reproduce the problem you are asking about and play around it until we find a solution.

@RonyCohen You can also consider creating a Codepen or JSFiddle of the code, and send us that. For example, https://codepen.io/pen/


Possibly the code's not working because in jquery you wrote $("#most-gifted"), which is an ID, but in the HTML, you wrote class="most-gifted", not id="most-gifted". Anyways, the code doesn't work, so we can't test it. (At least, that's the source of the errors in the console. I couldn't tell you if that's the reason your popups aren't opening, let alone closing.)


@LajosArpad I snippeted the code for this post. Noticed it wasn't working as well.
